# Markdownでリストの後に続けてコードを書きたい場合

Tags: markdown

Markdownでリストとコードブロックを続けて、

```
- リスト１
- リスト２

    var x = 1;
```

と書くと

> - リスト１
> - リスト２
>
>   var x = 1;

となってしまい、`var x = 1;`の箇所が意図したコードブロックになりません。
リストとコードの間に見出しを入れると上手くいくのですが、リストに続けてコードを書きたい場合は、どう書いたらよいのでしょうか？

[追記]以下のような出力結果にしたいです。

> - リスト１
> - リスト２
>
> ```
>   var x = 1;
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

間になにか挟む。インライン要素か、コメントでいい。

#### コメント

```
- リスト１
- リスト２

<!-- -->

    var x = 1;
```

---

- リスト１
- リスト２

```
var x = 1;
```

#### 空白エンティティ

```
- リスト１
- リスト２  

&nbsp;

    var x = 1;
```

---

- リスト１
- リスト２

```
var x = 1;
```

#### インライン要素空タグ

```
- リスト１
- リスト２

<i />

    var x = 1;
```

---

- リスト１
- リスト２

```
var x = 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

## リスト内にコードを書く場合

リストの場合は上下の空行とさらにコードに４個のスペースでのインデントが必要です。

```
1. foo

        int main() {
        }

2. bar
```

1. foo

   ```
   int main() {
   }
   ```
2. bar

## リストの下にコードを書く場合

上記の理由でリストを区切る必要があります。コードブロックには `<!-- language:javascript -->`の様にコードを示す表記が書けますので

```
1. foo
2. bar  aa

<!-- language:javascript -->

    var baz;
```

この様に書くと

1. foo
2. bar  aa

```
var baz;
```

となります。`<br/>`で無理やり改行を入れても良いと思います。

Comment: リストの中にコードブロックが含まれていますが、私が期待しているのはコードブロックがリストの外に出ている形です。質問の仕方が下手ですいません。追記します。

Comment: リスト外にコードブロックを書く場合について追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

pre、codeタグで囲ってしまう方法もありそうです。

```
- リスト１
- リスト２

<pre><code>var x = 1;</code></pre>
```

---

- リスト１
- リスト２

```
var x = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

表示だけなら空白の見出しを挿入しておくとか。H6(###### )あたりなら文章構造にも影響なさげ。

- aaa
- bbb

```
ccc
ddd
```